# Rails: Devise returning "Invalid Strategy..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

Not really sure what happened here, as Devise *was* working until recently.

In a nutshell, I've got Devise configured to work with Omniauth.  When I attempt to run my local server, I get a few problems.

The terminal presents a warning:

```
You provided devise_for :users but there is no model User defined in your application
```

When I attempt to actually visit the site in a browser, I get:

```
Invalid strategy rememberable
```

I've checked my user model, devise initializer, and routes, and all seem to check out.  I've also verified the tables exist in my database, and are accessible.  Here are the individual files:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :twitter_oauth, :oauthable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    case omniauth['provider']
    when 'facebook'
      self.apply_facebook(omniauth)
    when 'open_id'
      self.email = omniauth['user_info']['email'] if email.blank?
    end
    authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'], :token =>(omniauth['credentials']['token'] rescue nil))
  end

  def facebook
    @fb_user ||= FbGraph::User.me(self.authentications.find_by_provider('facebook').token)
  end

  def password_required?
    (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
  end

  protected

    def apply_facebook(omniauth)
      if (extra = omniauth['extra']['user_hash'] rescue false)
        self.email = (extra['email'] rescue '')
      end
    end
end
```

Devise initializer

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me@config-initializers-devise.com"
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.stretches = 10
  config.pepper = "..."
end
```

routes.rb

```
Project::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
  resources :authentications
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also using OmniAuth and Devise in my http://eq2mission.flame.org/ site, so I have quite a bit to compare directly with.

Here are the differences I can see between my use and yours:

(1)  I do not have the devise flags for :twitter_oauth or :oauthable in my user model.

(2)  I do have devise :validatable in my user model.

Other than that, it looks like we've both started from a common base since the code is so similar.

Comment: that was it, actually. It looks like I had some leftover baggage from a previous authorization method I was using.